# 2D array of method pointers

Tags: c++

It's easier to explain what I'm trying to do with some code:

```
class Superclass {
public:
    enum TypeEnum {
        typeA,
        typeB,
        typeC,
        typeEnumCount,
    }

    void Check(Superclass& other) {
        if (checkTable[type][other.type]) { // check the method pointer isnt null
            if (this->checkTable[type][other.type](other)) { // call the method that returns a bool
                // do something
            }
        }
    }

private:
    static ??? checkFuncTable[typeEnumCount][typeEnumCount] = {
        {A::CheckAgainstA, A::CheckAgainstB, A::CheckAgainstC},
        {B::CheckAgainstA, ...
    }

    TypeEnum type;
}

class A : Superclass {
public:
    A() : type(typeA) {}

    bool CheckAgainstA(const Superclass& other) const {
        // do the check
    }

    bool CheckAgainstB(const Superclass& other) const {
        // do the check
    }

    ...
}

class B ...
```

My questions:
How do I declare the checkFuncTable array?
Is that the correct syntax of the method pointers in checkFuncTable?
How do I call a method from it?

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish? I feel like there should be a better way than

```
if (type == typeA && other.type == typeA) { 
    ACheckAgainstA(other);
} else if (type == typeA && other.type == typeB) {
    ACheckAgainstB(other);
} else if ...
```

but I also don't know if this is the best way either.

Comment: All members of native arrays must be the same *type*. Yours are not. Thus, the difficulty in coming up with the proper array type (because there isn't one). What is this code *really* trying to accomplish, as this has all the indicators of an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Update your question with that information.

Comment: you probably want to store `std::function` in a vector of vectors (dynamically sized arrays are not a c++ feature).